# How to display "content": in firefox?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Everything works fine in Chrome but Microsoft Edge and Firefox display only a small block of the checkbox's border. I tried background-image property but it doesn't work with my code - the image appears before the checkbox. I tried placing "my-icon" with background-image property and "checkbox-body-checkmark" in the div class but the checkbox is then messed up and doesn't work at all.

CSS:

```
.checkbox-body-checkmark{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 4px solid var(--main-color);
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000000;
}
.select-body-container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-body-container:hover input ~ .checkbox-body-checkmark{
    background-color: #adadad;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
}
.select-body-container input:checked ~ .checkbox-body-checkmark{
    background-color:#adadad;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
.body-type-font{
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.my-icon{
        content: url("Imgs/my-icon.svg");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
 <label class="select-body-container">
     <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="checkbox-body-checkmark my-icon"></span>
          <span class="body-type-font">My icon</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: the `content` css property is meant only to be used with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors

Comment: Have you invented a new use for the `content` property? Good invention. But invalid.

Comment: How this works fine in Chrome..?

Comment: Validate your css and then use an autoprefixer library

Answer (score -1):

Use this appeareance only for Firefox Browser:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{ 
    appearance: initial; # only this also works others are just for browser support
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
    -moz-appearance: initial;
}
```